# PHP session is lost , only in windows mobile WinCE plat form

Tags: php, windows, session, mobile, barcode-scanner

I have a web application  developed in php working fine in handheld scanners and  from desktop pc . Scanners with CE.net plat form  php session working fine.

But in windows mobile hand held scanners with WinCE platform session is not retaining  on redirection.

Th redirection is happening in the same php file which divided into sections based on parameters. 
Anyone suggest where and what to check on the dependency of OS , Mobile plat form Mobile IE

Comment: Have you defined `session_name()`?

Comment: Is the scanner actually sending back the session cookie?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use request parameters for passing session ID when visitor uses such browser. That browser probably doesn't set session ID cookie